# Unable to Connect to Localhost (MySQL Workbench on MariaDB Docker)

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, debian, mysql-workbench

I ran the following script:

```
docker run --detach --name mariadb-10.1.48 \
 --env MYSQL_USER=user --env MYSQL_PASSWORD='123' \
 --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc' \
 -v /mnt/data/database/db_mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
 -v /mnt/data/database/db_mysql_config/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf \
 mariadb:10.1.48
```

I already changed on my.cnf the following line "bind-address = 127.0.0.0" to:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

I can access locally via CLI. Using MySQL Workbench is giving me the error "**Unable to connect to localhost**"

PS: My enviroment is the following:
Docker on Debian 11, i'm using Windows on the same network as the server trying to connect to the database using MySQL Workbench.

Please, what can i do?
Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running it in a container so you'd have to forward the ports or connect to the container IP.

`docker inspect` will get you the container IP if that's what you want.

Otherwise, change your docker command to the following to forward the port to your local machine:

```bash
docker run --detach --name mariadb-10.1.48 \
 --env MYSQL_USER=user --env MYSQL_PASSWORD='123' \
 --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc' \
 -v /mnt/data/database/db_mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
 -v /mnt/data/database/db_mysql_config/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf \
 -p 3306:3306 \
 mariadb:10.1.48
```

Note, if I'm understanding correctly your debian machine isn't WSL. So, from windows, 0.0.0.0 is the IP of the machine running docker. 0.0.0.0 is all the available IPs of localhost

Comment: Omg. I completely missed this out, totally forgot about the ports! ‍♂️‍♂️ Thank you bro!